# how to copy an object over another without the two referencing each other?

Tags: javascript

Let's say we got this:

`this.myObject = {"id":1};`

and we want to store the state of my object as my object original as the following:

`this.myObjectORG  = this.myObject;`

then you go on your business and change props on your object like this

`this.myObject.id = 2;`

and to your surprise down the road, you realize that

console.log (this.myObjectORG.id) // also reports 2

Well, that's just how JS works & I'm not questioning that.

Is there a way to preserve the state of the myObject so I can do comparisons whether its properties changed since its original state?

At some point I'd like to be able to do something like this

```
if ( this.myObjectORG.id !== this.myObject.id ) {
   // but this condition is never true 
}
```

Comment: What you are basically asking for is, how to create a copy of an Object, so you can handle the Object and the copy indepedently. A simple search in a searchengine for "how to copy js Object" will lead you to n answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object#728694

If you understand, what your problem really is, it is much easier, to find an answer. Hope it helps you to tackle future questions, that arise

Comment: good point. agreed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help:-

An Object.assign method is part of the ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) standard and does exactly what you need.

var this.myObjectORG = Object.assign({}, this.myObject);

The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object.

Comment: lovely but there is a lot of ES5 people out there.

Comment: @AverageJoe and there are also polyfills for it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill

Comment: Alright guys, I'm sold! `var this.myObjectORG = Object.assign({}, this.myObject);` that is.